# Pass variable from tableView to prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

My ultimate goal is to go to another view controller while passing a variable.

here's my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let name : String=arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name") as! String
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "SecondSegue" {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        viewController.passedVariable = name
    }
}
```

as you can see, I am trying to pass the variable `name` to the function `prepareForSegue`. as i said, my ultimate goal is to pass a variable to another view controller and open that view.

right now, prepareForSegue can do that but i just need the variable passed. maybe there is a way to do that directly in `func tableView`?

Comment: Do you want it to segue when you click the cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var name: String?    

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        name = arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name") as? String
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SecondSegue", sender: nil)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            if name != nil {
                viewController.passedVariable = name!
            } else {
                 print("failed to get name from dictionary")
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe this is what you are looking for. Do not assign the variable name in cellForRowAtIndexPath, because this function is normally called many times throughout the tableViews lifespan. Also, "name" needs to be a class variable so that you can assign it in one function and pass it in another. cellForRowAtIndexPath is a function for assigning the values and UI of each individual cell of the tableView. There are very few times to do anything else with it.

Comment: please elaborate on this... "Do not assign the variable name in cellForRowAtIndexPath, because this function is normally called many times throughout the tableViews lifespan."

Comment: Every time that you call tableView.reloadData(), cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for every cell the table view has. You declaring the variable name inside that function first prevents it from being used outside of the function because it is local to the function, and second with your current design would always be equal to the last element of your tableView rather than any desired cell. If you wanted to set the value of name there you would have to setup another variable tracking the selected cell, and would just be extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

Put code in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Save the selected indexPath to an instance variable and invoke your segue.

In prepareForSegue, use the saved indexPath to load the string you need from your model and pass it to the destination VC (viewController).

Comment: can you post some code so i know where you're going with this?

Comment: I'm not a fan of posting code for such simple steps since I think it leads to copy/paste programming rather than real learning. However, @Sethmr gave you example code.

Answer (score 0):

I have another way of doing this by using sender. You can avoid global var in this case

1. Save your `var paramToPass = val` in your cell class first of all.
2. in the `sender` field you set the sender to be `yourCell`

   `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "xxx", sender: partnerCell)
   }`
3. in prepareSegue function:

   ```
   if segue.identifier == "xxx" {

       guard let partnerCell = sender as? PartnerTableViewCell else {
           return
       }

       yourDestinationController.param = partnerCell.paramToPass

   }
   ```